# Piped commands in paramiko

Tags: python, grep, pipe, paramiko

How do I run piped commands in paramiko? I'm doing this:

```
statement = 'grep thing file | grep thing2 | tail -1'
last_msg = conn.execute(statement)
```

and I get the output of `grep thing file` only.

Answer (score 10):

Because `grep` doesn't know how to handle `|`. Get ready for some nasty escaping:

```
statement = """sh -c 'grep thing file | grep thing2 | tail -1'"""
```

This creates a shell on the other side, and asks it to interpret the string `grep thing file | grep thing2 | tail -1`. The single quotes are necessary since `sh -c` accepts only a single argument.

That way, a shell will create the pipe for you, running all the commands. And you better be sure that the filename `file` doesn't contain spaces. If it does, try `"file"`.

As you can see, this quickly gets very ugly. I suggest you put the pipeline into a shell script. Then you can avoid the quotes and just run the script with `sh -c script.sh`.

Comment: awesome answer, it works!!! now how do i add variables into the statement? i did """ + variable + """, i got a unmatched ' error

Comment: @Templar `statement = """... grep %s file | grep %s ...""" % ("thing", "thing2")` Remember to *really* check your input, since you can make this execute *anything* you want on the other end, if you can alter any of the arguments.

Comment: ... for example if someone creates a file that reads `xxx file ; rm -rf . ;`. Remember that there are only two characters which are illegal in a unix filename are the 0 byte and `/`.

Comment: @AaronDigulla +1 for the great answer. As of the first "follow-up" by @Templar (in the first comment), I have a variable `pid` of a process I wish to get its memory consumption, so I wish to compose the command: `pmap <pid> | grep total | awk '{print$2}'`. So I run the following, after I open a connection successfully (NOTE that I'm using a "different" command of paramiko):  `command = """sh -c pmap %s | grep total | awk '{print$2}'""" % (str(pid))` and then: `stdout_, stderr_ = paramiko.SSHClient().exec_command(command)`  - but with no luck. Any help will be great !! Thanks !!

Comment: @GuyAvraham You must somehow turn the whole pipe into a single string argument because (as I said in my answer), `sh -c` expects a single "word" as argument. So in your case, you're passing "pmap" to the sh option -c and then `sh` sees `%s` which isn't a valid argument. For your case, I suggest you put the pipeline into a shell script. Then you can avoid the quotes and just run the script with `sh -c ./script.sh`.

Comment: This worked great for me. @Templar - please accept this answer to give rep where rep is due. (Better late than never.)