# How to edit crontab file present in the remote UNIX server using Python

Tags: python, unix, cron, paramiko

I am having a crontab entry in my Python code describing which script should be scheduled in the UNIX remote server at the specified time.

I am writing a Python script which will connect to the ssh using Paramiko, it will go to the specified crontab file path in the remote server -> open the crontab file -> add the crontab entry specified in the Python script at the end of the file (on the new line) -> save & exit the crontab file.

Please let me know how I can achieve this.

P.S. : I already know how to connect to the server using Paramiko. Just stucked at the file handling part in the remote server.

Answer (score 2):

```
crontab -l 2>/dev/null| cat - <(echo "your new crontab entry here") | crontab -
```

### Explanation

```
crontab -l
```

Outputs the current crontab to stdout.

```
2>/dev/null
```

[Optional] Supresses error messages from crontab -l.  You'll get an error message if there is no crontab entry for the user.  But that's not a problem.

```
cat - <(echo "your crontab entry here")
```

The `-` takes the input from the pipe (crontab -l) and uses it as the first thing to cat.  Then the rest appends your new crontab entry to stdout.  The [<()](https://superuser.com/questions/1059781/what-exactly-is-in-bash-and-in-zsh) syntax takes the output of the command inside and stores it in a temporary file.

```
crontab -
```

This sets the crontab entry to the stdin (which, thanks to the pipe, is all the stdout from the previous commands.)

**Edit:** It looks like you'll need to wrap the command with `bash -c` in order to get the pipes to work.  See this [stackoverflow entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592020/piped-commands-in-paramiko).

Or, you can send a series of commands to paramiko.  Just beware of concurrency.

```
crontab -l > /tmp/current.cron
echo "your crontab entry here" >> /tmp/current.cron
crontab /tmp/current.cron
```

Another alternative is:

```
crontab <(cat <(crontab -l 2>/dev/null) <(echo "your new crontab entry"))
```

Comment: Can I use this command in my script using subprocess Python module?

Comment: You could with shell=True.  But that would be on the local system.  Paramiko is for executing commands on remote systems over ssh.

Comment: Exactly. I need to edit crontab file over remote server only.

Comment: Found a bug in my solution.  I've edited it.  Notice the - after cat.

Comment: 1 QQ. Do I need to have Python installed on remote machine as well for this?

Comment: No, you don't.  It doesn't connect to Python on the remote system, it executes over SSH.  So, you do need an ssh daeamon running on the remote system.

Comment: @Rohit `python is not required on remote server`, on local m/c python and paramiko is required.
ssh should be enabled on the remote server

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how Paramiko works but if you could use shell you can just simply execute:

```
echo "new line" >> cron_file
```

This command will add a string `new line` as a new line to the file `cron_file`.